# How to turn a flashlight on/off with VR trigger buttons?

Tags: unity-game-engine, controller, user-input, virtual-reality

I am trying to make a flashlight that can be turned on and off using the right hand trigger button(I'm using an oculus quest 2). Nothing happens when I press the trigger though.

I'm using unity 2022.2.0f1 and I have the XR interaction toolkit(2.1.1) and the XR plugin management(4.2.1). I made an action map and attached a player input component to the XR origin with the action map. The script for turning the flashlight on and off is also on the XR origin. I'm aware that there is an XRI Defualt action map but when I tried to reference it the script it wasn't recognizing it, and after a while of trying to figure that out I just made a different action map.

This is the code I put in the script:

```
public PlayerControls playerActions;
    public bool flashlightOn;

    public GameObject flashlight;


    private void Awake()
    {
        playerActions = new PlayerControls();
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        flashlightOn = false;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if(playerActions.Player.RightHandTrigger.triggered && flashlightOn == false)
        {
            Debug.Log("On");
            flashlight.SetActive(true);
        }
        else if (playerActions.Player.RightHandTrigger.triggered && flashlightOn == true)
        {
            Debug.Log("Off");
            flashlight.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
```

I'm fairly lost as to what to do to get it to work. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated. I'm sorry if this is poorly written out, this is my first time posting on here.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an InputActionReference instead of an entire playerControl :

```
public InputActionReference triggerPressedRef;
```

In the inspector, put the "XRI RightHand Interaction/Activate" for triggerPressedRef. Then, to avoid listening to input in the update method, you can assign actions to input this way :

```
private void Start()
{
    triggerPressedRef.action.performed += SwitchFlashLight;
}

private void SwitchFlashLight(InputAction.CallbackContext ctx)
{
    flashlightOn = !flashlightOn;
    flashlight.SetActive(flashlightOn);
}
```

If it doesn't work, check if your XR origin is properly set up, by comparing it to the prefab given by the XR Interaction Toolkit : Assets/Samples/Xr Interaction Toolkit/2.1.1/Starter Assets/Prefabs (make sure you imported the starter asset sample in the package manager).